# Fortran: remove characters from a string

Tags: string, fortran

How do I remove characters from a string?

For example, I have a string called 'year', which I want to change from 4 characters to 2 chracters. It is defined like so:

`character(4) :: year = "2011"`

How do I truncate the string to 2 characters, so that instead of `year = "2011"`, it is `year = "11"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use `year(3:4)`; however, your string will still be four characters long, i.e. it will contain your two digits, and two blanks. To illustrate this, here's an example:

```
program trunc
   character(len=4) :: year = "2011"

   write(*,'(A,A,A)') '..', year, '..'
   year = year(3:4)
   write(*,'(A,A,A)') '..', year, '..'
end program trunc
```

This prints

```
..2011..
..11  ..
```

To really get `"11"` instead of `"11  "` you have to assign the value to a variable that can hold two characters only.

Comment: to get rid of the trailing and leading blanks, you can use trim(adjustl(string))

Comment: @Zhenya That is partly true. If you use 'trim' you don't REMOVE the blanks, you just display/deal with the non-blank characters. If you know how long your string's 'interesting' portion is you can also simply access the relevant substring. But as the OP asked about setting the variable to "11" exactly I assumed he didn't want to have the blanks sticking around.

Comment: Indeed, you're right, trim(str) does not change the length of a string. It might be a matter of taste, but I personally prefer to keep all the strings of a fixed large length, like character*99, so that I don't have to remember an exact length of each given string.

Comment: Are you sure  that `character(4)` :: year` creates an array of 4 characters (as opposed to a string of length 4?).  It seems to me that you'd need:   `character,dimension(4) :: year` or `character :: year(4)` for that one.  I'm not even sure if this syntax is actually standard -- compared to `character*4 year` which I see all the time (to declare a string, length 4)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `year(3:4)` but don't quote me on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
character(4) :: year = "2011"
character(2) :: yr2

yr2 = trim(year(3:4))
```

Here `yr2` is the intended two character string.

Comment: From the example in the question, `year(3:4)` is the length-2 character expression `'11'` and `trim(year(3:4))` is exactly the same.  In more general cases it may be a length-1 or length-0 character.  So, this doesn't seem to answer the question.  Finally, how do you intend that expression to be used?  `year=trim(year(3:4))` still leaves `year` as a length-4 character variable and the `trim` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `year(3:4)` with `year` declared as a deferred-length character to avoid trailing spaces. This is a Fortran 2003 feature so you need a compiler compatible with that, and you cannot initialize the variable in the declaration.

Example:

```
program deflen
   implicit none
   character(len=:), allocatable :: year 
   year = '2011'
   write(*,'(A,A,I0)') year,'_LEN=', LEN(year)
   year = year(3:4)
   write(*,'(A,A,I0)') year,'_LEN=', LEN(year)
end program deflen
```

This prints:

```
2011_LEN=4
11_LEN=2
```